# Prove that every trapezoid and every parallelogram is measurable and derive the usual formulas for their areas

Tags: calculus, area

My question is from Apostol's Vol. 1 One-variable calculus with introduction to linear algebra textbook.

> *Page 60. Exercise 3.* Prove that every trapezoid and every parallelogram is measurable and derive the usual formulas for their areas.

*Additional information:* These are list of the axioms that we are allowed to use:

1. *Nonnegative property.* For each set $S$ in $\mathcal{M}$, we have $a(S)\ge0$.
2. *Additive property.* If $S$ and $T$ are in $\mathcal{M}$, then $S\cup T$ and $S\cap T$ are in $\mathcal{M}$, and we have $$a(S\cup T)=a(S)+a(T)-a(S\cap T).$$
3. *Difference property.* If $S$ and $T$ are in $\mathcal{M}$ with $S\subseteq T$, then $T-S$ is in $\mathcal{M}$, and we have $a(T-S)=A(T)-a(S).$
4. *Invariance under congruence.* If a set $S$ is in $\mathcal{M}$ and if $T$ is congruent to $S$, then $T$ is also in $\mathcal{M}$ and we have $a(S)=a(T)$.
5. *Choice of scale.* Every rectangle $R$ is in $\mathcal{M}$. If the edges of $R$ have lengths $h$ and $k$, then $a(R)=hk$.
6. *Exhaustion property.* Let $Q$ be a set that can be enclosed between two step regions $S$ and $T$, so that $$S\subseteq Q \subseteq T.$$ If there is one and only on number c which satisfies the inequalities $$a(S)\le c \le a(T)$$ for all step regions $S$ and $T$ satisfying $S\subseteq Q \subseteq T.$, then $Q$ is measurable and $a(Q)=c$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Start from proving that every right triangle is measurable using axioms 2 and 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tony Piccolo gives the core of the idea in his comment, except his idea does not actually prove that right triangles are measurable. (**Edit:** I was wrong here: George Dirac showed that Tony's idea *does* work directly. I was not imaginative enough to see it. Sorry, Tony!)

First, prove that all right triangles are measurable and have the usual area formula. Do that by covering the triangle with strips of rectangles for the $T$ in axiom 6, filling it with strips of rectangles for $S$ in axiom 6, and showing that the usual area formula gives $c$ in axiom 6. (Axiom 2 will be used to add the areas of these rectangles.)

[image]

Then split any triangle into two right triangles to get the area formula for any triangle. Finally, split the trapezoid and rectangle into two triangles to get their area formulas.

A rigorous proof would need attention to many details, but this outline should work.

Comment: Thanks, I will follow your outline. I proved that all right triangles are measurable by different method. I showed that right triangle was intersection of two rectangles, and since, by axiom 5, every rectangle is measurable, the intersection of two would also be measurable. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: @GeorgeDirac: Yes, that would work. I did not notice that axiom 2 says that the intersection of two measurable sets is measurable.